# Iterating through the array of elements to get data

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

It is my first time using `puppeteer`, and I need some help with scraping.

I am trying to get data from the list of `Array` elements; first I should click to the first element, get the title, go back and then click on the second element in `array`, get the title, go back, etc.

I have tried many approaches, but none of them seems to work from me.

```
await page.goto(url);
const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
    let title = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a[class="Fw(b)"]'))
        .map(prvi => prvi.textContent);
    console.log(title.length);
    return {
        title
    };
});
browser.close();
return result;
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you post your html structure and explain what you want out of them

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```js
const links = await page.$$('a[class="Fw(b)"]');

for(const link of links) {
    await link.click();
    const prop = await link.getProperty('textContent');
    console.log((await prop.jsonValue()));
}
``
```